# Is covariance matrix of multivariate normal distribution always positive semi-definite?

Tags: covariance

Is covariance matrix of multivariate normal distribution always positive semi-definite? Can it be negative definite? What will happen if the covariance matrix is negative definite???

Answer (score -1):

To show that it is positive semi definite we need to show that $z^T\Sigma z \ge 0$ for all $z$:
\begin{align*}
  z^T\Sigma z &= \sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1} (\Sigma_{ij}z_iz_j) \\
&= \sum_{i=1} \sum_{j=1} (E[(X_i - EX_i)(X_j - EX_j)])z_iz_j\\
&= E \Bigg[ \sum_i \sum_j (X_i - EX_i)(X_j - EX_j) z_iz_j \Bigg] \ge 0\\
\end{align*}
So for any random vector $X$, the covariance matrix is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot. But I'm still wondering what will happen if it's negative definite. Does it mean that the variance would be negative?(which of course doesn't make any sense)